# How do you write a unit test for a trigger whose only function is to make a callout?

Tags: apex, unit-test, trigger, callout

What is considered a best practice for writing a unit test (to maintain code coverage) on a trigger whose sole function is making a callout (Which also means it has to use a future method)? Neither futures or callouts can be tested so there really isn't anything to do.

What I've been doing is firing an add and/or update and just asserting that it added or updated correctly. Since there is also code to skip the callout if it's a test even this doesn't really test anything. Is this about the best we can hope for right now?

Comment: Nice question, getting coverage on callout is something which has troubled me in the past.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both future methods and callouts can be unit tested.

To test future methods simply make your call to any future method between `Test.startTest();` and `Test.stopTest();` statements and the future method will return when `Test.stopTest();` is called.  See the documentation for the `Test` class here: [System.Test](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_test.htm)

Testing callouts is a bit trickier though.  Basically in your callout code you check to see if you're executing within a unit test context by checking `Test.isRunningTest()` and instead of getting your callout response from an `HttpResponse.send()` request, you return a pre-built test string instead.  There's one example of this method here: http://www.iterativelogic.com/unit-test-callouts-in-apex-code-part-2/

There's also an older example of callout unit testing that uses a static variable you set in your unit test.  Just replace that static variable with a call to `Test.isRunningTest()` and their example works fairly well as well.  That example can be found here: http://sfdc.arrowpointe.com/2009/05/01/testing-http-callouts/

Comment: Another approach to structuring your callout testing code to maximize code coverage http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Virtual_Callout_Testing

Answer (score 5):

There's a new feature coming in the next version to make testing callouts easier:
https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?id=08730000000iDaEAAU

Comment: I think I heard a rumor about public implementations of global interfaces as well.

Comment: Yep. That's in there.

Comment: Also, relevant to testing: test fixtures. Stick a CSV in a static resource and call Test.loadData() to create your test data from it.

Comment: Does the test fixtures feature bypass triggers and work on non-DML sObjects by chance (e.g. AsyncApexJob, BusinessHours)?

Comment: No, sorry, it works just like a normal bulk insert, except that it wires up FKs for you automatically.

Comment: @RichUnger with Foreign Keys wired up automatically, do I zip them up as two separate CSV files?